# Does this sentence follow the rule subject verb agreement?

Tags: verb-agreement

"Let the rain come down."

This sentence is part of the song.

Comment: Why do yoiu think it might not follow the rule? What do you think that it perhaps should be instead. note that song and verse often bend grammatical rules in service of brevity, striking imagery, meter and rhyme. what work have you done on this?

Comment: Im just asking, i thought it should be Let the rain comes down. Im just a new english learner. Pardon my stupidity

Comment: There is no stupidity here, i just weant to understand what you are thinkign so i know what to discuss in a response.

Comment: It's a special kind of imperative clause.

Answer (score 1):

We say this:

> The rain **comes** down.

But we also say this:

> Let the rain **come** down.

The reason for this is that *let* is one of several [*causative verbs*](https://poligo.com/en/articles/grammar/all-about-causative-verbs). The main causative verbs include *make / force*, *have / get*, *let / allow*, and *help*. These verbs function as auxiliary verbs.

When a causative verb is used, it is followed by a subject and another verb in its *infinitive* form (either with or without *to*). The infinitive form of a verb does not follow normal subject-verb agreement.

---

The general construction of sentences using causative verbs is as follows:

> **(Make / have / let)** the rain come down.
>   **(Force / get / allow)** the rain *to* come down.

The causative verb *help* can be followed by either the complete infinitive or the bare infinivite:

> **Help** the rain (to) come down.

It doesn't matter what the subject is, the verb at the end will not follow normal subject-verb agreement, but always be in its infinitive form.

Answer (score 0):

> Let the rain come down

is a set phrase, almost an idiom. It is the standard form for this phrase. It does seem asa if "the rain" is a singular thing, an the verb form should be "comes". But remembeer that "Let X [do] Y" is in the imperitive. It is a command. If one said

> The rain comes down in sheets today.

it is descriptive, and the normal pattern of agreement is used. Similarly:

> The rain falls alike on the just and the unjust, likewise shines the sun.

(Matthew 5:45) shows agreement.

But consider

> The elder said: "Go West, young man", and so he goes West, as he has been advised.

The order is "Go West", the descriptive phrase is "goes west".

Comment: This has nothing to do with idioms or set phrases. *Let* is a causative verb that follows a particular grammatical rule.

Answer (score 0):

> *Let the rain come down.*

I'd call this an idiomatic open *let*-imperative; "open" in the sense that it is not understood as a directive to the addressee(s) to allow or permit something. In that respect, it's only a peripheral member of the speech act category of directives.

Nevertheless, it has it common with the central directives in that it defines a future action and calls for it to be carried out.

Syntactically, it contains the catenative verb "let" with an NP object and a bare infinitival clause as second complement. The NP object "the rain" is direct object of "let", and the semantic (understood) subject of "come down".