# why we used plural verb with singular subject in the following sentence?

Tags: verbs, subjects

1.He does not want to tell a lie.
he is a singular subject but we used want instead of wants why ?
2.Does he write a letter?
Here he is also singular and we used write instead of writes
please explain

Comment: This is called *do-support* and I think our sister site is probably the place to go...

Comment: Related: [Does this sentence follow the rule subject verb agreement?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/206398/does-this-sentence-follow-the-rule-subject-verb-agreement/206401#206401).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Want" is not (here) a plural verb: it is the base form (sometimes called the infinitive), because the auxiliary "do/does/did" **always always always** takes the base form of the following verb. The same for "write".

"Does" is the verb that is (3rd person) singular, to agree with "he".